# How to use Power Query to recreate this SQL OVER PARTITION?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, powerquery, window-functions

I'm trying to recreate the following logic I create in SQL in Power Query. I'm tried doing it by grouping by the OrderNumber column, but I wasn't able to use a rank function or anything similar. I'm trying to keep the query folding enabled if I can.

```
SELECT * -- columns
FROM(
    SELECT j.*,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY OrderNumber
            ORDER BY LineNumber, DateReceived DESC, StatusName DESC
        )
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] j
) ord
WHERE
    ord.rn = 1
```

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to achieve with this query. I want to rank each order by their LineNumber, in order to select only lowest LineNumber for each order, and in the case of a tie, I use the OrderStatus to determine a winner.

[image: Sample order data]

Comment: This is much easier to answer if you have example data showing input and output.

Comment: https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2018/06/14/ranking-method-choices-in-power-query/ gives good outline of ranking in power query